# I need to know how to take the selected item of a comboBox and make it appear on a windows form application?

Tags: c#

I have a windows form application with a ComboBox on it and I have some strings in the box. I need to know how when I select one of the strings and press my create button, how can i make that name show up on another windows form application in the panel I created. 
Here is the code for adding a customer

```
public partial class AddOrderForm : Form
{
    private SalesForm parent;

    public AddOrderForm(SalesForm s)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        parent = s;

        Customer[] allCusts = parent.data.getAllCustomers();

        for (int i = 0; i < allCusts.Length; i++)
        {
            Text = allCusts[i].getName();
            newCustomerDropDown.Items.Add(Text);
            newCustomerDropDown.Text = Text;
            newCustomerDropDown.SelectedIndex = 0;
         }
```

now when i click the create order button I want the information above to be labeled on my other windows form application.

```
        private void newOrderButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //get the info from the text boxes


            int Index = newCustomerDropDown.SelectedIndex;
            Customer newCustomer = parent.data.getCustomerAtIndex(Index);              


            //make a new order that holds that info
            Order brandSpankingNewOrder = new Order(newCustomer);
            //add the order to the data manager
            parent.data.addOrder(brandSpankingNewOrder);
            //tell daddy to reload his orders
            parent.loadOrders();
            //close myself
            this.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: Do you own the other application?  If you do, you can use interprocess communications of some sort, like Remoting, WPF or SendMessage.  If you don't, you'll need to use SendKeys.

Comment: What do you mean own the other application? Its all on multiple forms and classes in my one SalesManager Project through visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

The context is not very clear to me, but if I got it right, you open an instance of AddOrderForm from an instance of SalesForm, and when you click newOrderButton you want to update something on SalesForm with data from AddOrderForm.

If this is the case, there are many ways to obtain it, but maybe the one that requires the fewer changes to your code is this one (even if I don't like it too much).

Make the controls you need to modify in SalesForm `public` or at least `internal` (look at the Modifiers property in the Design section of the properties for the controls). This will allow you to write something like this (supposing customerTxt is a TextBox in SalesForm):

```
parent.customerTxt.Text = newCustomerDropDown.SelectedItem.Text;
```